# VueJS: How to pass Vue.prototype.$http to a different Vue application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I maintain a Vue component library for my company. So far they're pretty simple. Basically Vuetify dialogs, menu systems, etc. I'm using vue-cli 3 to package it up and share it in our repository. My users can then simply import it from a simple npm-update and include them with "import @mycompany/vue-components"

However now I'm trying to write a component that needs the axios instance from the calling application. Our calling applications typically set axios like so as a convention:

```
import axios from "axios";
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

I'd like to know how I can pass this instance of axios to my external component or somehow make sure I'm using the same instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass it. It should already be using the same `$http`.

As long as you execute `Vue.prototype.$http = axios;` before `const app = new Vue(....);`, every child components inside `app` can access the same `$http` by using `this.$http`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/g7zpo826/2/